# How can I get and split a part of string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, object, split, tags

I would like to each `<div class="person"> { /*JSON stuff/* }`  to be a separate element in a list of object. It's mixed in with other html content(`...html tags...`). I have a string like this from a html file:

```
...html tags...
<div class="person">
{
    "name":"Bob",
    "age":20,
    "color":"blue"
}
</div>
...html tags...
<div class="person">
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "color":"green"
}
</div>
...html tags...
```

It cannot be predicted how many persons will be. I think that I will use Regex, Json or Substring. My problem is that there are many other content surrounds these persons and I do not know what would be a simplest solution to each elements to be a separate element in a list of object.

For example I have a class like this:

```
class Person
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int age {get;set;}
}
```

I would like to upload `List<Person>` list from this html.

Comment: What the hell is generating this? Json within HTML?

Comment: Your intro sentence discusses repeats, what repeats exactly do you want to eliminate?  Any div with same name?  Any div with all the same attributes?

Comment: It's not obvious (from what you are showing us) what it is you are talking about, and what you want to do.  You talk about splitting a string.  What string (or strings)?  Can you show us an example of something that "contains repeat", and what you want to do when whatever that is happens.

Comment: I agree with all the above comments. However, if you are trying to get the 'JSON' out from the html, I would use some kind of JavaScript to first extract the JSON out from the page and then post it back to the back end (possibly ASP.NET/Core C# code). Using JQuery you could do something like `var obj = $.parseJSON($('.person').val())` and then then use an api/ajax call to process it at back end

Comment: @KJohnson I have a html content in my string. In this content contains dives with class like `<div class="person">`. That's what repeats. This is what I would like to get and split its elements to list.

Comment: @Flydog57 so `<div class="person">` are repeats. Its content I would like to split to list. For example I have a Person class (there are data members like name, age in this class) and I want to upload a list of Person.

Comment: Sorry, still not following.  Showing what you have and what you want would help.  It sounds like you want each `<div class="person"> { /*JSON stuff/* } </div>` to be a separate element in a list of strings.  Is that right?  Given your `...html tags...` notes, it sounds like it's mixed in with other html.  Is it in a C# string?  Is it the result of CSHTML or ASPX rendering?  It's not obvious.  Sorry we can't help until you explain some more (i.e., you should edit your question so that the reader can understand your question).

Comment: @Flydog57 sorry, I try to clarify. Yes, that right, but not to list of string. I would like to list of object (like `List<Person>`). There are mixed in with other html. It is a C# string.

Comment: Edit your question so that everyone can see what you are trying to do.  Show some C# code, show your html-ish stuff as a string, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps...

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            // Just get your input loaded into a variable called input
            var input = @"
                <div class='person'>
                {
                    'name':'Bob',
                    'age':20,
                    'color':'blue'
                }
                </div>
                <div class='dog'>
                {
                    'name':'Jim',
                    'age':30,
                    'color':'green'
                }
                </div>
                <div class='person'>
                {
                    'name':'John',
                    'age':30,
                    'color':'green'
                }
                </div>
            ".Replace("'", "\"");

            Regex personContents = new Regex("<div class=\"person\">(.+?)</div>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            var persons = personContents.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().Take(6).Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(x.Groups[1].Value.Trim())).ToArray();
            var names = string.Join(",", persons.Select(x => x.name));
            Console.WriteLine($"names={names}");
        }

        class Person {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int age { get; set; }
            //public string color { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code prints "Bob,John".  This doesn't address filtering out the duplicates but that would be easy enough with LINQ's Distinct() method to grab just the unique records.

Comment: Thanks, it is so helpful but I get this error at linq: `'MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. The input/string mixed in with other html content. Do you have any idea, how can I get it (the input)? I tried to use `indexOf()` and `Substring()`, but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Okay, I dont get error message if I use `Cast<Match>()` like: `jsonItems.Matches(input).Cast<Match>().Select...`

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I deserialize (JSON) exclusively the persons class? Can I limit how much element will be deserialize? For example just the first 6 results.

Comment: Yes, change the line to be `var persons = jsonItems.Matches(input).Take(6).Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(x.Groups[0].Value)).ToArray();` to only process the first six.

Comment: Thank you! Can you help me how can I change this regex to get just name and age properties between {}? That's how I tried, but not a good solution: `^.*\b(name|age|{|})\b.*$`.

Comment: I'd just remove the color attribute from the Person class and let the JSON deserializer only map the properties in the target class.  I'm not sure you gain much by trying to change the raw JSON for each person.

Comment: Thank you! Another problem is that the json is mixed with other html content. For example, in html contains `<div class = "dog">` with the same JSON properties as the `person class`. Should I use Regex / indexOf to get all person class?

Comment: I've modified to use a regex that only selects the divs with name="person".